# Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './v4' is not defined by "exports"

Tags: node.js

I got this error when using uuidv4.

```
Failure: Package subpath './v4' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\mycomp\Desktop\Programming\Javascript\Serverless\Serverless Framework\node_modules\uuid\package.json
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './v4' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\mycomp\Desktop\Programming\Javascript\Serverless\Serverless Framework\node_modules\uuid\package.json
```

I already installed uuid and require it in my code

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
```

Here's the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "aws-sdk": "^2.702.0",
  "moment": "^2.27.0",
  "serverless-offline": "^6.4.0",
  "underscore": "^1.10.2",
  "uuid": "^8.1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

ECMAScript Module syntax:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
uuidv4(); // ⇨ '9b1deb4d-3b7d-4bad-9bdd-2b0d7b3dcb6d'
```

CommonJS syntax:

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
uuidv4(); // ⇨ '1b9d6bcd-bbfd-4b2d-9b5d-ab8dfbbd4bed'
```

Comment: can you provide some context here? how is this solving the issue?

Comment: Same, this exact code is giving the error

Comment: Version 7 of the `uuid` package deprecated deep imports `require('uuid/v4')`, and version 8 removed them. That's why the code in the question doesn't work, since it uses version 8 of the package, but tries to import it using `require('uuid/v4')`. This answer solves the problem by not using deep imports.

Answer (score 11):

Another option

```
const uuid = require('uuid');
uuid.v4(); // "c438f870-f2b7-4b2c-a1c3-83bd88bb1d79"
```

Answer (score 7):

We had the same error with v1 uuid module (v8.3.2).

Solved this, adding following entry to `exports` section of *installed* uuid `package.json`(**inside your `node_modules`**):

```json
"./v1": "./dist/v1.js"
```

Full export section of my projects' `node_modules/uuid/package.json`:

```json
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "node": {
        "module": "./dist/esm-node/index.js",
        "require": "./dist/index.js",
        "import": "./wrapper.mjs"
      },
      "default": "./dist/esm-browser/index.js"
    },
    "./package.json": "./package.json",
    "./v1": "./dist/v1.js"
  },
```

The problem remaining i now need to keep this modification across dist installs... :/

This could be fixed with a patch on uuid source itself?

EDIT: Didn't require the module in our own source. It is a dependency of jest (via some jest reporting sub-pkg).

EDIT: Alternatively, rolling back to uuid dep to `v7.0.3` may fix this issue too, see comment below.

Comment: I'd recommend submitting this as PR to the uuid git repo. This error is still occurring on the latest version (v8.3.2). I dropped all the way back to the v7.0.3 build to be able to require the module correctly.

Comment: thanks for figuring out which build to rollback to to fix :)

Comment: @risingfish can you vote +1 my answer anyhow? :) also, i am not involved into uuid repo. atm i am reluctant to open a PR as i am not sure if maintainers will consider this a fix itfp. they might have their reasons to have broken things? you know what i mean? :) furthermore, this change only fixes v1 ...

Comment: created a PR https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/pull/584

Comment: Why do you insist on using deep require syntax?

Deep requires have intentionally been deprecated in uuid@v7.x and removed uuid@v8.x, upgrade instructions are given in the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#800-2020-04-29), more context in https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/pull/361#issuecomment-585397739.

Does the [accepted answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62555064/1053532) work for you?

Comment: @ctavan unfortunately the accepted answer is not applicable in our case, because we are not importing the packet ourselves. it is used in our build tooling and as the newer version is loaded by legacy direct deps on our side, the mentioned error appears. other than in a sub-dep of jest (jest-reporter) also in webpack worker-loader plugin. but these are only examples. it shows dropping support for the legacy way of importing the module on uuid project side has potential effects on (n-th degree) consumers.

Comment: This problem is hard to diagnose without a reproduction case. Please feel free to report the issue at https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/ providing a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can address it.

Comment: Yes, well, we have only solved it with enforcing usage of an older uuid dep all over, which does work nicely. All I would want to suggest to uuid maitainers is to keep backward compatible with legacy distro modes, instead of insisting on idealistical concepts.

Comment: @Tchakabam I think that the correct approach here is to fix it in the package that is importing uuid wrong. That package was intended to use an older version, and even if the deep require were added back to 8.x, there could be other subtle differences as well. Can you please run `npm ls uuid` and post a list of which of your dependencies depends on uuid?

Comment: yes that is correct in theory - but in practice i wouldn't possibly fork such a dependency and the dependent package where i would have to make it point to the first (or n other forks needed depending on the depth of the dependency in the tree :D)

Comment: Don't think this is feasible when time to ship to production comes.

Answer (score 0):

docs:

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

> Like in CommonJS, module files within packages can be accessed by appending a path to the package name unless the package's package.json contains an "exports" field, in which case files within packages can only be accessed via the paths defined in "exports".

https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#main-entry-point-export

> When the "exports" field is defined, all subpaths of the package are encapsulated and no longer available to importers. For example, `require('pkg/subpath.js')` throws an `ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED` error.
>
> This encapsulation of exports provides more reliable guarantees about package interfaces for tools and when handling semver upgrades for a package.
>
> It is not a strong encapsulation since a **direct require of any absolute subpath** of the package such as `require('/path/to/node_modules/pkg/subpath.js')` will still load subpath.js.

you can get the absolute path of `node_modules/pkg` with something like

```
function get_absolute_module_path(name) {
  // this can throw MODULE_NOT_FOUND
  const main_export = require.resolve(name);
  const suffix = `/node_modules/${name}/`;
  const idx = main_export.lastIndexOf(suffix);
  if (idx == -1) {
    throw new Error(`failed to parse module path from main export path ${main_export}`);
  }
  const end = idx + suffix.length - 1;
  return main_export.slice(0, end);
}

console.log(get_absolute_module_path("pkg"));
```

different package managers will produce different paths, for example

```
npm:
/tmp/tmp.OPv0pmip4T/node_modules/cowsay

pnpm:
/tmp/tmp.ls6MykLOOC/node_modules/.pnpm/cowsay@1.5.0/node_modules/cowsay
```

Comment: What's the solution for 3rd party packages?

Comment: what are "3rd party packages"?

Comment: This issue affected a package I wasn't importing directly, so no control over its codebase. That is 3rd party. Anyway, nvm. I skipped the initialization command for vue apollo and have all but abandoned the project that required it

Comment: "no control over its codebase" sounds like a use-case for [patch-package](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) (but different package managers will install transitive dependencies in different paths)