# create-react-app not working due to postcss

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, postcss

I am currently learning react, and started a new app with `create-react-app`.

I navigated into the new app, then ran `npm start`.

I got this error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module '~/Desktop/forms-test/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/lib/tokenize'
    at createEsmNotFoundErr (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:907:15)
    at finalizeEsmResolution (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:900:15)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:432:14)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:472:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:867:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/Desktop/forms-test/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/lib/safe-parser.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
```

Any help would be very useful.

I am running Mac OS Catalina, using `npm`, and running `zsh`. I am using node version 14.13.1

Comment: I suggest to install your dependencies again which would help

Comment: @tmhao2005 What command would do that?

Comment: If you use npm, `npm i`. Or using yarn, just simply run `yarn`

Comment: @tmhao2005 `npm i` did not fix anything.

Comment: Didn't you check if file `node_modules/postcss/lib/tokenize.js` is now existed?

Comment: @tmhao2005 Yes, it exists.

Comment: Hmmm. Weird. Do you have a reproducible repo?

Comment: @tmhao2005 No, I am just testing react for myself. I made no modifications after running the command. I will put more details in the question.

Comment: I fixed the problem, somehow. I changed the `postcss` dependency in `postcss-safe-parser` to `8.1.4` and back to `8.1.0` and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For others digging around, I followed the instructions on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63884223).

```
rm yarn.lock
yarn install
```

And that reinstalled everything and properly exported the lib/tokenize path inside of `node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/package.json`.